# How can I use SQLAlchemy to do "mysql explain"

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, explain

I have a sql like:

```
DBSession().query(Model).filter(***)
```

and I want to explain this sql using `SQLAlchemy`.

Answer (score 21):

You want to [compile your SQLAlchemy query into a string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined); use the correct dialect and use literal values for bind parameters

```
query = DBSession().query(Model).filter(***)
# you should have an engine reference used to create the DBSession object
sql = query.statement.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
```

You can then use that to ask for a MySQL explanation:

```
DBSession().execute(f'EXPLAIN {sql}')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can prepare your explain sql string like this:

```
'EXPLAIN' + query.compile(
    compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True},
    dialect=mysql.dialect()
)
```

Advantage is query has parameters filled in.