# Programmatically measure database query complexity in Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is this possible in python/sqlalchemy?

When I write an endpoint which retrieves a list of records, I might accidentally make my query very inefficient without realizing.

Is there a way to measure the complexity of database queries in a method/unit test and throw an error if too many transactions take place?

In my example, I am using strawberry for providing a graphql router. On more than one occasion, I've made the following mistake, which involves an additional database query being made for each `ParentModel` in the list to retrieve the `ChildModel`. To get around this, I can make the `ChildModel` be loaded eagerly in the initial query. I would like to be able to make it very obvious to myself if my method will result in a large number of database queries.

```
import strawberry


@strawberry.type
class ChildGQLSchema:
    id: int

    @classmethod
    def from_model(cls, model: ChildModel):
        return cls(
            id=model.id,
        )


@strawberry.type
class ParentGQLSchema:
    id: int

    @strawberry.field
    def children(
        self, info, page: int = 1, limit: int = 20
    ) -> list[ChildGQLSchema]:
        # Unless explicitly loading the children, this will result in a
        # query to the database for each parent.
        models = (
            session.query(ChildModel)
            .filter(ChildModel.parent_id == self.id)
            .all()
        )


@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def parent(self, info, id: int) -> ParentGQLSchema | None:
        model = session.query(ParentModel).filter(ParentModel.id == id).first()
        if not model:
            return None
        return ParentGQLSchema.from_model(model)
```

Comment: See [SQLAlchemy EXPLAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261551/how-can-i-use-sqlalchemy-to-do-mysql-explain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing an example of a N+1 query problem. You'll find a lot of resources/examples online using that as a search term.

Libraries like https://github.com/jmcarp/nplusone can help detect them for you.

It's still a good idea to learn more about N+1's b/c libraries like that usually can only catch the easy/obvious instances.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was just missing the vocabulary to find solutions.

Now I know the name, I'm in a much better position to investigate further.